# Do logic on apache tile attributes

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jsp-tags, apache-tiles

In my apache tiles config file, I have a section like this:

```
<definition name="admin/*/*" extends="adminLayout">
    <put-attribute name="key" cascade="true" value="{1}" />
</definition>
```

Then, in my JSP, I am would like to do some logic on the tile attribute.
Something like:

```
<c:if test="${key == 'value'}">
    // do something
</c:if>
```

where key comes from the tile attribute.

**How can I access this tile attribute inside the expression language?**

I have tried

```
<c:set value="<tiles:insertAttribute name='key'/>" var="theKey"></c:set>
```

and

```
<c:if test="${<tiles:insertAttribute name='key'/> == 'value'}">
```

and both times the raw tiles xml is used as the comparing string - it doesn't get replaced by the attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Tiles extras](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tiles-extras/):

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"
    xmlns:tilesx="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles-extras"
    version="2.0">

    <tilesx:useAttribute id="keyJspVariable" name="key" classname="java.lang.String" />

    <c:if test="${keyJspVariable== 'value'}">
       // do something
    </c:if>
```

Documentation example: https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/list-attributes.html